# Modify numpy array column by column inside a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, in-place

Is there a way to modify a numpy array inside a loop column by column?

I expect this could be done by some code like that:

```
import numpy as n

cnA=n.array([[10,20]]).T
mnX=n.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
for cnX in n.nditer(mnX.T, <some params>):
    cnX = cnX+cnA
```

Which parameters should I use to obtain `mnX=[[10,23],[12,24]]`?

I am aware that the problem could be solved using the following code:

```
cnA=n.array([10,20])
mnX=n.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
for col in range(mnX.shape[1]):
    mnX[:,col] = mnX[:,col]+cnA
```

Hovewer, in python we loop through modified objects, not indexes, so the question is - is it possible to loop through columns (that need to be modified in-place) directly?

Comment: Are you aware of numpy's array slicing syntax? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing

Comment: You say matrix, but your code says ndarray? Those are two different things

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected and extended my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just so you know, some of us, in Python, do iterate over indices and not modified objects when it is helpful. Although in NumPy, as a general rule, we don't explicitly iterate unless there is no other way out: for your problem, the simplest approach would be to skip the iteration and rely on broadcasting:

```
mnX += cnA
```

If you insist on iterating, I think the simplest would be to iterate over the transposed array:

```
for col in mnX.T:
    col += cnA[:, 0].T
```

Comment: Thanks, Jaime. Of course, I could use broadcasting for this simple task, but in my initial task I need to do more complex operation on column. What I actually need is to know the syntax how to modify array mnX by modifying it column by column in place without using column indices. Your example leaves mnX unchanged.

Comment: @Apogentus Jaime's example does modify `mnX`: `col` is a view of `mnX`, and modifying it inplace (`+=`) changes `mnX`. In fact, it's precisely "modify[ing] array mnX by modifying it column by column in place without using column indices".

Comment: Tested... It works and completely answers my question! Thank you!